# im writing a code for counting the frequency of adjacent letters in python

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
line=input()
#taking a sentence

d1=1
#count variable

ln=len(line)
for i in range(0,ln):

    if line[i]==line[i+1]:

        d1+=1
    else:

        print(line[i],d1)
        d1=1
```

**sample test cases1

- aaabcaaaa
- **sample output1** a 3 b 1 c 1 a 4

**

**my wrong output

- aaabcaaaa
- **sample output1** a 3 b 1 c 1

**
in my output, I'm not getting the last frequency of the last character

Comment: I'm not getting the frequency of last characters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading and Compressing a picture with RLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456480/reading-and-compressing-a-picture-with-rle)

Comment: first of all, `range(ln)` is the exact same as `range(0, ln)`, so you can remove the 0

Comment: Ya I know about range(ln)==range(0,ln) @Shazers

Answer (score 0):

You only print the number if the next char is different. but the last char has no next char.
change your if statement to:

```
if i != ln - 1 and line[i] == line[i + 1]:
```

Comment: No it is not working its throwing "string index out of range" error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one last statement at the end, because it no longer goes into the `else` statement to print out the last letter frequency

Try

```
d1=1
#count variable

ln=len(line)
for i in range(0,ln-1):
    if line[i]==line[i+1]:

        d1+=1
    else:
        print(line[i],d1)
        d1=1

if d1 > 1:
    print(line[i],d1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
line=input()
d1=1
ln=len(line)
output=""
for i in range(0,ln-1):
    if line[i]==line[i+1] and i!=ln-1:
        d1+=1

    else:
        output+=line[i]+str(d1)
        d1=1

output+=line[i+1]+str(d1)#this extra line solves my question#
print(output)
```

**Thanks to both of you for  your respons **